# Upgrade from 20.04 to 20.10 failed

Tags: upgrade

I bit the bullet today and decided to upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10, but got a 'failed' message near the end.

After the boot I then went into a terminal and just did a `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and got the following which doesn't mean a great deal to me.  I'd appreciate a workaround if possible, as my default solution would be to simply do a clean install!

---------8< ----------------------------

```
Setting up openmpi-bin (4.0.3-6ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrupt: slave link s
ame as main link /usr/bin/mpicc
dpkg: error processing package openmpi-bin (--configure):
 installed openmpi-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned erro
r exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
:
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin; however:
  Package openmpi-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopenmpi-dev:amd64:
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin (>= 3.0.0-1); however:
  Package openmpi-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopenmpi-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up er
ror from a previous failure.
                            No apport report written because the error message i
ndicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                        Errors were encountered 
while processing:
 openmpi-bin
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now edited to add that I have now tried the suggestion to run update-alternatives, but that gave me this:

```
update-alternatives: error: /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi corrupt: slave link same as main link /usr/bin/mpicc
```

Also as requested, the output of 'cat /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi'

---------8< ----------------------------

```
auto
/usr/bin/mpicc
libmpi++.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi++.so
libmpi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmpi.so
mpi-c.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/mpi-c.pc
mpi-cxx.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/mpi-cxx.pc
mpi-fort.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/mpi-fort.pc
mpi.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/mpi.pc
mpiCC
/usr/bin/mpiCC
mpiCC.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.1.gz
mpic++
/usr/bin/mpic++
mpic++.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.1.gz
mpicc
/usr/bin/mpicc
mpicc.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.1.gz
mpicxx
/usr/bin/mpicxx
mpicxx.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.1.gz
mpif77
/usr/bin/mpif77
mpif77.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.1.gz
mpif90
/usr/bin/mpif90
mpif90.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif90.1.gz
mpifort
/usr/bin/mpifort
mpifort.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/mpifort.1.gz

/usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
50






/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.openmpi.1.gz

/usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpif77.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpif90.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif90.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpifort.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpifort.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/include
50
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ompi-c.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ompi-cxx.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ompi-fort.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ompi.pc
/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpiCC.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpic++.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpicc.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpicc.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpic++.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpicxx.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpif77.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif77.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpif90.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpif90.openmpi.1.gz
/usr/bin/mpifort.openmpi
/usr/share/man/man1/mpifort.openmpi.1.gz
```

Comment: Well, the problem is /etc/alternatives/mpi seems to be messed up.  You could try "sudo update-alternatives --remove-all mpi", then "sudo apt install --reinstall openmpi-bin".

Comment: [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1335861/edit) to show the complete output of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi`

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/+bug/1970985/comments/3

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem when upgrading from 20.04.5 to 22.04.1. Solved by:

```shell
sudo rm -f /etc/alternatives/mpi* /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi*
sudo apt install openmpi-bin
```

The inspiration came from StackOverflow, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62464085/openmpi-bin-error-after-update-kubuntu-18-04-to-20-04

Comment: OP, you should accept this answer